# BizTalk 2013r2 and Biztalk 2016 in one machine

Tags: biztalk

There are 2 application one developed in BizTalk 2013R2.
Other one in BizTalk 2016.

Now I need to support and do changes for the application in one machine.
There is no common artifacts for these.

Is this possible to handle both these application in one machine?
Can 2 BizTalk version possible to install in one machine?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

As you need to have the BizTalk SDKs installed, and I don't think you can have both installed in parallel, then no, you can't have a Development environment for both BizTalk 2013R2 and BizTalk 2016.

Comment: What about the version 2016 and 2020?There are 2 application one developed in BizTalk 2016. Other one in BizTalk 2020.

Now I need to support and do changes for the application in one machine. There is no common artifacts for these.

Is this possible to handle both these application in one machine? Can 2 BizTalk version possible to install in one machine? Please help

Comment: No you can't have two versions of BizTalk on the same machine.  You could however just develop everything in BizTalk 2106, and export it as a MSI and import it into BizTalk 2020, but you are asking for trouble.